# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions in a neighborhood of zero

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So I have a sequence of functions $(f_n(s))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which all have a fixed point at zero and I want to show that this sequence converges to a function $f_\infty (s)$ which is defined in a neighborhood of zero.

I also know the Jacobians of the functions at the point zero. So my first intuition was working with Taylor's formula, but that does not really work out as I can't really control the remainder.

So now I have been looking at the difference of the Jacobians and see that $(J_{f_n}(0))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Now my question: Is it sufficient for the sequence of Jacobians at a fixed point of a sequence of functions to be a Cauchy sequence, to conclude that the sequence of function converges in a neighborhood of that point?

My intuition says yes, because if the Jacobian gets arbitrarily close to some well-defined matrix, there has to be some neighborhood where the function is defined. But, as intuition can be a mathematician's worst enemy at times, I would be very grateful if somebody could help me here.

Comment: Your title says "uniform convergence".  What's up with that? Is that an otherwise unstated assumption, or is it a desired conclusion?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, English is not my first language. It is a desired conclusion, I need to show that the sequence converges uniformly to a function in a neighborhood of zero

Comment: You have the "complex-analysis" tag here.  Did you mean to imply that your functions are complex-analytic, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f_n$ given by $$f_n(s)=\begin{cases}2s-2/n&x>1/n\\0&-1/n\le s\le 1/n\\2s+2/n&x<-1/n\end{cases}.$$

They all have $0$ as a fixed point, and converge uniformly to $f(s)=2s$, which also has $0$ as a fixed point.  But they are all differentiable at $0$, with derivatives $f'_n(0)=0$.  But $\lim_n f'_n(0) \ne f'(0)=2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Are there assumptions I can make to avoid this? For example, would it help if the functions are smooth?

Comment: Of course.  You could insist that the functions and their derivatives converge uniformly, for instance. But then your conclusion becomes too easy to be interesting.